# How to filter a list based on multiple conditions?

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, math, search

I am trying to filter a `List` with multiple conditions. The main thing is, I must use the condition if it is `true` and not if it is `false`. If the condition is `false` I should not use that to filter. Below is my code

```
void performFiltering(bool homeVisits, bool onTheSpotServices)
  {
    //Check for home and on the spot filtering
    if(homeVisits==true)
    {
      filteredOrganizationList = orgList.where((org) => org.homeVisits==true);
    }
    else if(onTheSpotServices==true)
    {
      filteredOrganizationList = orgList.where((org) => org.onTheSpotService==true);
    }
    else if(homeVisits==true && onTheSpotServices==true)
    {
      filteredOrganizationList = orgList.where((org) => (org.onTheSpotService==true) ||(org.homeVisits==true) );

    }

  }
```

here I have made simple `if-else` statements. Nothing serious. But I can't do this when there are more conditions. Luckily it is just 2 conditions, but I have much more to come.

Also carefully notice that I have used `OR` Command in the last statement. That means get results where either `homeVisits=true` or `onTheSpotServices=true`

Whats the most effective way of handing this?

Comment: `orgList.where((org) => homeVisits && org.homeVisits || onTheSpotServices && org.onTheSpotService || ... etc etc)`

Comment: @pskink: Great. Please provide your comment as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is no need for a cascade of multiple `if-else`s

instead use a single `where` with a custom `test` function:

```
filteredOrganizationList = orgList.where((org) =>
  homeVisits && org.homeVisits ||
  onTheSpotServices && org.onTheSpotService ||
  ... // rest of your filter tests      
);
```

Comment: btw, i just realized if both `homeVisits` and `onTheSpotServices` are `true` it will work a bit different as your original code but i think you will call `performFiltering` with only one filter criteria, if not, you have to use:  `orgList.where((org) => homeVisits? org.homeVisits : onTheSpotServices? org.onTheSpotService : ... etc etc)`